# How to fully unbind a GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER?

Tags: macos, opengl, graphics, memory-leaks, vertex-buffer

I'm working on a multithreaded app that simultaneously renders geometry to multiple FBOs.  I'm experiencing a leak (as described on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20249457/64860)).

I've been able to narrow it down a little — if I make one change, it stops leaking — but I can't figure out why.

On each of 4 threads (each with its own shared context), I'm doing the following each render cycle:

```
// Upload

positionBuffer = getUnusedArrayBufferFromPool();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*4*vertexCount, positions, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

{
    GLuint vertexArray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);

    elementBuffer = getUnusedElementArrayBufferFromPool();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int)*elementCount, elements, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);



// Render (possibly on a different context)

GLuint vertexArray;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);

glUseProgram(programName);
{
    GLint positionAttribute = glGetAttribLocation(programName, "position");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)positionAttribute, 4 /* XYZW */, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*4, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)positionAttribute);

    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)elementCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    glDisableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)positionAttribute);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
glUseProgram(0);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);



// Cleanup (possibly on a different context)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
throwArrayBufferBackInPool(positionBuffer);

//glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);
//glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 0, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
//glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
//throwElementArrayBufferBackInPool(elementBuffer); // Why does this leak if we recycle it?
glDeleteBuffers(1, &elementBuffer);
```

If I swap the last 2 lines — if I throw the element buffer back into the pool instead of deleting it each render cycle — OpenGL Driver Monitor indicates a huge leak.

But I'd prefer to pool it, since calling `glDeleteBuffers()` each frame is really slow.

What am I missing?  I assume I'm failing to unbind `elementBuffer` from something — and that something is holding on to a reference to it, causing the leak — but I can't figure out what.

---

**Edit:** Just tested on a different system (Mac OS 10.6) — on that system, it leaks if I recycle *any* buffers.

**Edit:** I modified my application so that `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is pooled separately from `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, and so that `elementBuffer` is consistently bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.  But it still leaks if I `throwElementArrayBufferBackInPool(elementBuffer);`.

**Edit:** Clarified why I'm creating and deleting a VAO during Upload and during Rendering — because they might happen on different shared GL contexts, and VAOs can't be shared between contexts.

**Edit:** I modified my application to provide zero-size buffer data before throwing the buffers back into the pool, but it still leaks just as quickly.

Comment: Any chance you could explain/show how `throwElementArrayBufferBackInPool (...)` is implemented? VAOs are container objects, if you delete a buffer object that is bound to one (really the only buffer object binding that VAOs track is the **element** buffer, the vertex pointers work differently) while that VAO itself is not active, then the buffer object is not completely deleted until the VAO's reference to it is removed. If the VAO is active when you delete the element buffer, then it is automatically unbound. This *may* be relevant in this situation, but I need to see the implementation.

Comment: You could probably solve all of this by calling `glBufferData (...)` with 0 for size and keeping a pool of reserved but empty buffer names for reuse instead of deleting buffer objects. This will free the data store immediately (relatively speaking) without having to wait for all references across all contexts and container objects to be removed.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: The pool is just a simple threadsafe wrapper for a C++ std::vector.  I just posted a source excerpt here: https://gist.github.com/smokris/7711889

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thanks. I modified my application to provide zero-size buffer data before throwing the buffers back into the pool (see modified source code above), but it still leaks just as quickly.

Comment: Well, I was not suggesting this was a solution to get rid of dangling references to element array buffers. What it does, however, do is free any memory associated with those buffers (after any pending GL operation that uses them finishes). This way, even though you have names floating around that are effectively lost to the void, you do not have any wasted GPU storage. It is not a perfect solution, but it will solve some issues while you track the real culprit down. In my own work, I have VAOs and other OpenGL objects completely wrapped - the engine shadows all of their states for easy debug.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Oh! Of course that wouldn't solve the dangling references issue. Not sure what I was thinking. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Your buffer pool is used for binding `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` as well as GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER objects. Worse, you're first using `elementBuffer` for binding a `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but then carry on using it for an `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. I haven't fully wrapped my head around it, but somewhere between mixing the namespaces and the inconsistent use of bindings I'd put my money on that.

My suggestion: Create a separate pool of buffer names for `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` use and make sure you're using it consistently for only that.

Comment: I modified my application (and the example code above) so that `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is pooled separately from `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, and so that `elementBuffer` is consistently bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.  But it still leaks if I `throwElementArrayBufferBackInPool(elementBuffer);`.